# set drag and drop child node to display json array in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, drag-and-drop, jstree

So question says by themselves. I did an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p9d2r77o/5/)

or or look on this code:

html

```
<div id="jstree">
       <ul>
       <li>Root
       <ul>
            <li>Parent1
                <ul>
                   <li>Child1</li>
                   <li>Child2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Parent2
                <ul>
                   <li>Child1</li>
                   <li>Child2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <input id="left" type="file" class="file" data-upload-url="/upload">
 </div>
```

js

```
var array = [
    {
        "name": "Parent1",
        "id": "1",
        "description": "An extended Bootstrap table with radio, checkbox, sort, pagination, and other added features. (supports twitter bootstrap v2 and v3) "
    },
    {
        "name": "Parent2",
        "id": "2",
        "description": "A jQuery plugin to select multiple elements with checkboxes :)"
    },
    {
        "name": "Parent1",
        "id": "3",
        "description": "Show/hide password plugin for twitter bootstrap."
    }
];

var array2 = [
 {
        "subname": "Parent101",
        "subid": "101",
        "description": "An extended Bootstrap table with radio, checkbox, sort, pagination, and other added features. (supports twitter bootstrap v2 and v3) "
    },
    {
        "subname": "Parent202",
        "subid": "202",
        "description": "A jQuery plugin to select multiple elements with checkboxes :)"
    },
    {
        "subname": "Parent101",
        "subid": "303",
        "description": "Show/hide password plugin for twitter bootstrap."
    }
];
var $table = $('#table');
var $study = $('#jstree');

$(function () {

    $table.bootstrapTable({
        formatNoMatches: function () {
            return "This table is empty...";
        }
    });


     $('#jstree')
        .on('select_node.jstree', function(event, data){
            // ===== Initialize parent =====
            var loMainSelected = data;
            uiGetParents(loMainSelected);
            function uiGetParents(node) {
                try {
                    var level = node.node.parents.length;
                    var elem = $('#' + node.node.id);
                    var parent = node.node.text;
                    for (var ln = 0; ln <= level - 1; ln++) {
                        elem = elem.parent();
                        var child = elem.children()[-1];
                        if (child != undefined) {
                            parent = child.text;
                        }
                    }
                    console.log(parent);
                }
                catch (err) {
                    console.log('Error in uiGetParents');
                }
            }
            // ===== Click event on node =====
            for(var i = 0; i < data.selected.length; i++) {
                var node = data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text;
                if (node == "Child1") {
                $(function () {
                        $table.bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', 
                        {
                            data: array, 
                            columns: [
                                {
                                    title:"Name", 
                                    field:"name"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    title:"Id", 
                                    field:"id"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    title:"Description",
                                    field:"description"
                                }
                            ]
                        }); 
                      });
                }
                else if (node == "Child2"){
                 $(function () {
                        $table.bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', 
                        {
                            data: array2, 
                            columns: [
                                {
                                    title:"Subname", 
                                    field:"subname"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    title:"Subid", 
                                    field:"subid"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    title:"Description",
                                    field:"description"
                                }
                            ]
                        }); 
                      });
                }
            }
        })
        .jstree({
        "core" : {
            "themes": {
                "url": true,
                "icons": true,
                "dots": true
            }
        }
     });
    });
```

I want to create drag and drop node, so user could drag it and drop it into to the droppable window and he'll see the table with data. Separately everything works fine. Jstree is loading, eventHandler on click works well and you can see table by clicking and even drag and drop window works fine and display every file which user will drop into it but how to connect all of this stuff, has anyone idea?

Comment: Did you solve you problem?

Comment: @NikolayErmakov nope still have some problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you will have to use the `dnd` plugin and listen to drag-drop event as below. Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/9v25fx6k/).

```
$(document).on('dnd_stop.vakata', function(e, data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.nodes.length; i++) {
        var node = $('#jstree').jstree().get_node(data.data.nodes[i]).text;
        if (node == "Child1") {

            $table.bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
                data: array,
                columns: [{
                    title: "Name",
                    field: "name"
                }, {
                    title: "Id",
                    field: "id"
                }, {
                    title: "Description",
                    field: "description"
                }]
            });

        } else if (node == "Child2") {

            $table.bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
                data: array2,
                columns: [{
                    title: "Subname",
                    field: "subname"
                }, {
                    title: "Subid",
                    field: "subid"
                }, {
                    title: "Description",
                    field: "description"
                }]
            });

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm using this plugin on my page, just forgot to provide it in sample.. I still can figure out how to listen it

Comment: Did you check the demo? Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, I checked the demo and it's not exactly what I'm looking for, I want when I drag node child1 and drop it into drag and drop window it will show me the table inside of this window

Comment: Do you drop child1 on the div with text `This table is empty`? Because when I do this the table gets filled with data.

Comment: I'm sorry something for my absolutely late, this fiddle is exactly what I need! Thank you a lot!!

Comment: I'm sorry for annoying but could you help me with this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141672/drag-and-drop-event-doesnt-fire-from-jstree